# How do I create an instance for this package with Vue?

Tags: vue.js, npm, logging, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm trying to use this logging package I found in my Vue Project. https://github.com/xpl/ololog

I want to be able to use the logger in my whole project and all my components. Do I have to import the package in every single component I want to use it in or is there a way to make it global?

How can I make an instance for it? Sorry, I am confused about this. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can either:

A. Import the logger on every component

B. Add an [instance property](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/adding-instance-properties.html) to make the log function accessible to all components:

```js
// When you initialize your Vue app
Vue.prototype.$log = myLogFunction

// Now $log is available on all Vue instances via `this`
this.$log("my log");
```

`A` is more explicit, `B` is more convenient.